# TransactionException: Could not register synchronization for container transaction

Tags: hibernate, jta

I am using WebLogic, Spring and Hibernate. I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Could not register synchronization for container transaction
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.afterTransactionBegin(CMTTransaction.java:72)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:166)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
at com.abc.framework.xyz.dao.MyDAOImpl.getHibSession(MyDAOImpl.java:209)
```

The piece of code that is causing this is :

```java
private Session getHibSession() {
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction(); // this line is causing the issue
```

Should I use 'openSession' or 'getCurrentSession'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Spring - Hibernate application it is suggested to open and close session 
for eg. you can autowire the sessionFactory bean and then use the session for a 
database transaction

```
         session=sessionFactory.openSession();
         Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
         CustomObj obj= new CustomObj ();
         session.save(obj);
         tx.commit(); 
         session.close();
```

make sure to close the session in finally block to not have open connections
in case of exceptions.